# AWS Lamba Serverless .Net C# App Error

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am getting an error when trying to use a Lamba Function in AWS Lamba using the Visual Studio Template.  When I deploy to lamba and try to test my function I get the below error.  I did not really change anything about the project, just using it as it was given.

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is but am not able to do it.  This is really my first time learning about Lamba and Serverless Architecture.  Any ideas?

```
START RequestId: 65fd2b6c-f52e-11e6-ae87-4f4e1852036a Version: $LATEST
Incoming  requests to [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request starting   https://apigateway--   
Unknown error responding to request: NullReferenceException:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Internal.PathTokenizer.get_Count()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.TreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.<RouteAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__15.MoveNext()
NullReferenceException:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Internal.PathTokenizer.get_Count()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.TreeEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Tree.TreeRouter.<RouteAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteCollection.<RouteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.<ProcessRequest>d__15.MoveNext()
[Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost: Request finished in 4680.1609ms 0  
END RequestId: 65fd2b6c-f52e-11e6-ae87-4f4e1852036a
REPORT RequestId: 65fd2b6c-f52e-11e6-ae87-4f4e1852036a  Duration: 7974.44 ms    Billed Duration: 8000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 46 MB
```

Comment: Does `https://apigateway--` appear anywhere in your project? Seems like it tries to make a http request to that url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faced the same issue. You need to connect to AWS explorer in visual studio before creating a project. Create a separate account in AWS console portal and try again.